# How can i refactor/organise my routes in gin golang that contains a lot of routes?

Tags: go, routes

As you can see, i got a lot of routes. How can i structure/refactor this in a better way? Is there a better way or is it not needed? This code is part of my request handler, communicating with database(mongodb). I couldn't find documentation about this at the gin golang github. If there was a way to shorten it, that would be great.

```
package routes

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "foldername/db"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func UserRoute(router *gin.Engine) {
    router.GET("/address/:query", func(c *gin.Context) {
        param := c.Param("query")
        page := c.Request.URL.Query().Get("page")
        pageStr, err := strconv.Atoi(page)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        query, err := db.ReturnSingleAddress(param)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        countTransactions, err := db.CountTransactions(param)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        transactions, err := db.ReturnTransactions(param, pageStr, 15)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"address": query, "transactions": transactions, "total_transactions": countTransactions})
    })
    router.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
            "datetime":     db.ReturnDateTime(),
            "countwallets": db.CountWallets(),
        })
    })
    router.GET("/tx/:query", func(c *gin.Context) {
        value := c.Param("query")
        query, err := db.ReturnSingleTransfer(value)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"response": query})
    })
    router.GET("/coinbase/:query", func(c *gin.Context) {
        value := c.Param("query")
        query, err := db.ReturnSingleTransfer(value)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"response": query})
    })
    router.GET("/rank/:query", func(c *gin.Context) {
        value := c.Param("query")
        query, err := db.ReturnRankAddress(value)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"response": query})
    })
    router.GET("/richlist", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"richlist": db.ReturnRichlist()})
    })
    router.GET("/blocks", func(c *gin.Context) {
        query, err := db.ReturnLatestBlocks()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"response": query})
    })
    router.GET("/validators", func(c *gin.Context) {
        query, err := db.ReturnValidators()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"response": query})
    })
    router.GET("/transactions", func(c *gin.Context) {
        query, err := db.ReturnLatestTransactions()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"response": query})
    })
    router.GET("/contracts", func(c *gin.Context) {
        query, err := db.ReturnContracts()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"response": query})
    })
    router.GET("/alltransactions/:query", func(c *gin.Context) {
        value := c.Param("query")
        query, err := db.ReturnAllTransactionsByAddress(value)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"response": query})
    })
    router.GET("/walletdistribution/:query", func(c *gin.Context) {
        value := c.Param("query")
        wallets, err := strconv.ParseUint(value, 10, 64)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        query, err := db.ReturnWalletDistribution(wallets)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"response": query})
    })
    router.GET("/blockhashbn/:query", func(c *gin.Context) {
        value := c.Param("query")
        queryHash, err := db.ReturnHashToBlockNumber(value)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"response": queryHash})
    })
    router.GET("/block/:query", func(c *gin.Context) {
        value := c.Param("query")
        intValue, err := strconv.ParseUint(value, 10, 64)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        query, err := db.ReturnSingleBlock(intValue)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"response": query})
    })
    router.GET("/contractcode/:query", func(c *gin.Context) {
        value := c.Param("query")
        query, err := db.ReturnContractCode(value)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"response": query})
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like to move my handler functions into separate files and directories which represent the API, so that you only need to reference the handlers instead of using inline functions. In your case I would suggest restructuring your paths, so that you can group them to common root paths.